# Returning the first word in an array that begins with "wa"

Tags: ruby

I have an array that contains a mixture of strings and symbols.

```
array = ["candy", :pepper, "wall", :ball, "wacky"]
```

The aim is to return the first word that begins with the letters `"wa"`.

Here is my code:

```
def starts_with_wa
  deleted_words = array.delete_if{|word| word.class == Symbol}
  ## deletes the symbols in the original array
  deleted_words.find do |w|
  ##it should iterate through the deleted_Words array but it shows error of undefined local variable or method "array" for main:Object
    w.start_with?('wa')
  end
end

starts_with_wa
```

Comment: What is the exact question here ??

Comment: `detect` is Array's method to find first match.

Comment: Note that "starting with letters `"wa"` " and "starting with a substring `"wa"`" mean different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `array` to your method, otherwise, it is not visible in the scope of the method. Furthermore, I suggest a simple refactoring:

```
array = ["candy", :pepper, "wall", :ball, "wacky"]

def starts_with_wa(words)
  words.find { |word| word.is_a?(String) && word.start_with?('wa') }
end 

starts_with_wa(array)
#=> "wall"
```

Comment: `word.is_a?(String)` – the variable name makes this check look redundant :-)